# Spinner Validation using android saripaar

Tags: android, validation, spinner, saripaar

How can I validate my `Spinner` Android Saripaar?

I have declared my `Spinner` in the following manner.

```
@Select(order = 8)
Spinner spin_country;
```

and this is my `onValidationFailed()` method.

```
@Override
public void onValidationFailed(View failedView, Rule<?> failedRule) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String message = failedRule.getFailureMessage();
    if (failedView instanceof Spinner) {
        failedView.requestFocus();
        // What should i do here??
    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to validate whether spinner is selected or not

Comment: yes ...whether it is selected or not

Answer (score 4):

If you want a simpler solution than provided by `user3508814`, just do the following (no need to track `spinnerSelections`):

Annotation used

```
@Select
Spinner spin_country;
```

onValidationFailed

```
    @Override
    public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
        for (ValidationError error : errors) {
            View view = error.getView();
            String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(this);

            // Display error messages
            if (view instanceof EditText) {
                ((EditText) view).setError(message);
            }
            else if (view instanceof Spinner) {
                ((TextView) ((Spinner) view).getSelectedView()).setError(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

Use a map to track spinners and their text views (if you have multiple).

```
private Map<View, TextView> spinnerSelections = new HashMap<View, TextView>();
```

Use OnItemSelectedListener to record changes to the spinner selection.  This fires when the activity loads, so your default selection will be tracked.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            spinnerSelections.put(parent, (TextView) view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Set errors on spinner's text view

```
@Override
public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
    for (ValidationError error : errors) {
        View view = error.getView();
        String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(this);

        if (view instanceof EditText) {
            ((EditText) view).setError(message);
        }
        else if (view instanceof Spinner) {
            spinnerSelections.get(view).setError(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I set my spinners to not be focusable so I don't see any error messages but I do get the red exclamation point.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Which saripaar annotation did you use to make the validation?

Comment: @LTroya I used the `@Select` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case, Saripaar the `Spinner` validation will fail if the first item (index 0) is selected in your `Spinner`.

Considering these are the items on your `Spinner`.

```
-- Country --
Albania
France
India
Sri Lanka
...
```

The validation will fail if `-- Country --` is selected, because it is the first item (index 0) on the `Spinner`.